# Varios Input-Group en linea Boostrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, entrada, layout

Buen día!

Les comento.. soy nuevo utilizando Bootstrap 4 y estoy intentando, dentro de un formulario, poner en un mismo renglón varios input de la clase `input-group`.

Estoy intentando lo siguiente:

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="uno">Primer Label</label>
    <div class="input-group col-4 mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon34">https://example.com/users/</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uno" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>


    <label for="basic-url">Segundo Label</label>
    <div class="input-group col-4 mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo que pasa, es que el `<Label>` se posiciona a la izquierda del `<input>` cuando lo que pretendo es que se posicione arriba, como pasa usando la clase `.form-row`

Intenté probando distintas combinaciones y buscando en internet y no tuve suerte!

¿Alguien sabe cual sería la manera correcta para hacerlo?

Aclaro, que no utilizo `form-inline` ya que es un formulario bastante largo (+30 inputs), donde en ciertos casos muestro 2 o 3 en un mismo renglón, pero se da la situación en la que tengo que aclarar la medida, por lo cual me veo obligado a utilizar un `input-group`

Desde ya muchísimas gracias por leer la pregunta!

**EDIT**

Creo que me expresé mal, lo que busco sería esto

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
```

Pero usando `input-group` en lugar de `form-group` para poder hacer uso de los prepend.

De nuevo gracias!

Comment: Quieres que el prepend este en la parte de arriba?

Comment: @Angel me refería a ponerlos en linea en un form normal, como se hace con la clase form-row, ahí edite la pregunta para que quedara más clara, Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo es necesario agregar unos cuantos div:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aqui te va un ejemplo: [EJEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/angel123456/ze8kf43d/14/)

Para la parte responsive tendrías que ponerle algo más de cabeza.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! me solucionaste la vida :P

Answer (score 1):

Espero haber entendido tu problemática, ya casi lo tenias resuelto, era cosa de jugar con unas clases css de bootstrap.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label for="basic-url">Primer Label</label>
         <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
               <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label for="basic-url">Segundo Label</label>
         <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
               <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
</html>
```